# Can't reboot from external HD after partitioning

Tags: partition

I was able to boot from my external HD formatted in Mac OS Extended until I partitioned it with Disk Utility. According to Disk Utility the Mac partition is still bootable but the drive no longer shows up in Select Startup Disk or when I reboot the Mac with option key. Is there a way to make it show up as a bootable disk again without having to reformat it? I'm using OS10.9.5

Below is the output from `diskutil list`.

```
/dev/disk0 
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0 
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Samsung Mac             251.1 GB   disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk1s3 
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Samsung PC              248.1 GB   disk1s4
```

Information from sudo blessed for the external HD:

```
finderinfo[0]: 152860 => Blessed System Folder is /Volumes/Samsung500/System/Library/CoreServices
finderinfo[1]: 592373 => Blessed System File is /Volumes/Samsung500/System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi
finderinfo[2]:      0 => Open-folder linked list empty
finderinfo[3]:      0 => No alternate OS blessed file/folder
finderinfo[4]:      0 => Unused field unset
finderinfo[5]: 152860 => OS X blessed folder is /Volumes/Samsung500/System/Library/CoreServices
64-bit VSDB volume id:  0x2BD688998DF36E9A
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please add the output from `diskutil list` to your question.

Comment: Could you please add the output from `sudo bless --info <mount point of external drive>`? (For example: `sudo bless --info /Volumes/ExternalHD`)